# Passing XML code to Get Repose from API using Coldfusion

Tags: php, xml, api, coldfusion

I had the following PHP code that posts XML data and retrieves the status as successful post or not. This code was sent by the company to test the api, but as the development is done using ColdFusion I wrote a code, given below in ColdFusion, Its sends an OK response but returns an error code as per behavior or the API.

```
<?php 
define('blueEx', "http://benefit.blue-ex.com/api/post.php");
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BenefitDocument>
<AccessRequest>
<DocumentType>1</DocumentType>
<TestTransaction>Y</TestTransaction>*For Testing purpose, after testing leave it blank
<ShipmentDetail>
            <ShipperName></ShipperName>
            <ShipperAddress></ShipperAddress>
            <ShipperContact></ShipperContact>
            <ShipperEmail></ShipperEmail>
            <ConsigneeName>Tayyab</ConsigneeName>
            <ConsigneeAddress>202-N,DHA,Lahore</ConsigneeAddress>
            <ConsigneeContact>03004306499</ConsigneeContact>
            <ConsigneeEmail>fusioner@gmail.com</ConsigneeEmail>
            <CollectionRequired>Y</CollectionRequired>
            <ProductDetail>Some Product</ProductDetail>
            <ProductValue>200</ProductValue>
            <OriginCity>ISB</OriginCity>
            <DestinationCountry>PK</DestinationCountry>
            <DestinationCity>LHE</DestinationCity>
            <ServiceCode>BG</ServiceCode>
            <ParcelType>P</ParcelType>
            <Peices>1</Peices>
            <Weight>1</Weight>
            <Fragile>N</Fragile>
            <ShipperReference>9010191</ShipperReference>
            <InsuranceRequire>N</InsuranceRequire>
            <InsuranceValue></InsuranceValue>
            <ShipperComment>xxxx</ShipperComment>
</ShipmentDetail>
</AccessRequest>
</BenefitDocument>';
$c = curl_init();     
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, blueEx );
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sphere.technologies:sphere.tech");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml'=>$xml) );
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type=application/soap+xml', 'charset=utf-8'));
    $result = curl_exec ($c);
    $xres = simplexml_load_string($result);
    $st = $xres->status;
    $no = $xres->message;

    echo $st . ' - ' . $no;
?>
```

and its working Returning a Success Status

I want to have the code written in ColdFusion and I wrote the following Code

```
<cfset objCFHttpProperties = {
    Useragent = "#CGI.http_user_agent#",
    Username = "sphere.technologies",
    Password = "sphere.tech"
    } />
<cfxml variable="xmlString">
    <BenefitDocument>
        <AccessRequest>
            <DocumentType>1</DocumentType>
            <TestTransaction>Y</TestTransaction>
        <ShipmentDetail>
            <ShipperName></ShipperName>
            <ShipperAddress></ShipperAddress>
            <ShipperContact></ShipperContact>
            <ShipperEmail></ShipperEmail>
            <ConsigneeName>Tayyab</ConsigneeName>
            <ConsigneeAddress>202-N,DHA,Lahore</ConsigneeAddress>
            <ConsigneeContact>03004306499</ConsigneeContact>
            <ConsigneeEmail>fusioner@gmail.com</ConsigneeEmail>
            <CollectionRequired>Y</CollectionRequired>
            <ProductDetail>Some Product</ProductDetail>
            <ProductValue>200</ProductValue>
            <OriginCity>ISB</OriginCity>
            <DestinationCountry>PK</DestinationCountry>
            <DestinationCity>LHE</DestinationCity>
            <ServiceCode>BG</ServiceCode>
            <ParcelType>P</ParcelType>
            <Peices>1</Peices>
            <Weight>1</Weight>
            <Fragile>N</Fragile>
            <ShipperReference>9010191</ShipperReference>
            <InsuranceRequire>N</InsuranceRequire>
            <InsuranceValue></InsuranceValue>
            <ShipperComment></ShipperComment>
        </ShipmentDetail>
    </AccessRequest>
</BenefitDocument>
</cfxml>
<cfhttp url="http://benefitx.blue-ex.com/api/post.php" method="post" result="result" attributecollection="#objCFHttpProperties#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/soap+xml"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" name="xmlString" value="#xmlString#" />
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

But this code returns the error Status

I've been trying to resolve the issue but cannot come to resolve. Can Someone Help, where I went wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this thread could be helpful in resolving the issue. Thanks to BKBK at Adobe fourms who sorted things out

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2392683